# Database Design - Dashboard

Tags: database, database-design, sqlite

I'm trying to design database schema for a web app that serves as a dashboard.

1. There can be any number of Dashboards (User can create new dashboard)
2. Each Dashboard is associated with Teams (About 10-25 teams per dashboard)
3. Each Teams has Members (About 10 members per team)
4. Each Member has a name, role, email
5. Every Team submits weekly reports through a form (About 12 questions. All questions are same for every team except one question)
6. The Form responses are stored in the database.
7. Based on the weekly form responses, the warnings are displayed on the Dashboard (web app). There are fields like Teams issues, Number of meetings missed by a member, etc

What I've done so far
[image]
Is this the correct way to design the database? Can this be improved? I'm using Django to create the web app and SQLite3 database.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are off to a good start.  Based on your business rules that you listed, you might want expand your design based on #7.  For example, you mention that team's attend meetings, yet there is no branch for this action by member.

One other area that I see for improvement is #5.  Although at the start you may think there are at most 12 questions, your database model should be built to accommodate future requirements: your form responses should be composed from a minimum of four tables (Survey, Question, SurveyQuestion, SurveyResponse).

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of four tables for the survey questions and responses.